# Cannot find symbol in Java application

Tags: java

I am working on a simple text-based rpg battler program as an introduction to Java.  I seem to have a decent understanding of the majority of code, but I have ran into a couple of issues.

The issues I am having are in the Project class.

In my switch statement I am trying to use the setSpells() and setArrows() methods and I am getting a "cannot find symbol" error message.  I realize that this is probably due to something I have set up incorrectly in the sub-classes, but I am unsure what that is.

The second issue is in the print statement pulling the character name by use of c.getName().  The c part of that statement gives the same error message.

Is there something simple that I am misunderstanding in these situations?  Any help resolving this would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Here is my main project class file:

```
package project;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Project {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Welcome to Lands of the Sun\n");

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String choice = "y";
    while (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
    {
        System.out.print("Please choose your class (wizard or elf): \n");
        String classChoice = sc.next();
        sc.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Please choose a name for your " + classChoice + ": ");
        String charName = sc.next();
        sc.nextLine();

        int healthVal = (int) (Math.random() * 10) + 1;

        switch (classChoice) {
            case "wizard":
                {
                    Character c = new Wizard();
                    c.setName(charName);
                    c.setGold(25);
                    c.setHealth(healthVal);
                    c.setSpells(10);
                    break;
                }
            case "elf":
                {
                    Character c = new Elf();
                    c.setName(charName);
                    c.setGold(25);
                    c.setHealth(healthVal);
                    c.setArrows(10);
                    break;
                }
        }

        System.out.print(c.getName());

        System.out.print("Continue? (y/n): ");
        choice = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println();
    }
}

}
```

Here is my Character class:

```
package project;

public abstract class Character {
private String name;
private int gold;
private int health;
public static int count = 0;

public Character()
{
    name = "";
    gold = 0;
    health = 0;
}

public Character(String name, int gold, int health) {
    this.name = name;
    this.gold = gold;
    this.health = health;
}

public void setName(String name)
{
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName(){
    return name;
}

public void setGold(int gold)
{
    this.gold = gold;
}

public int getGold()
{
    return gold;
}

public void setHealth(int health)
{
    this.health = health;
}

public int getHealth()
{
    return health;
}
@Override
public String toString()
{
    return "Name: " + name + "\n" +
           "Gold: " + gold + "\n" +
           "Health: " + health + "\n";
}

public static int getCount()
{
    return count;
}

public abstract String getDisplayText();
}
```

Here is my Wizard sub-class:

```
package project;

public class Wizard extends Character {
private int spells;

public Wizard()
{
    super();
    spells= 0;
    count++;
}

public void setSpells(int spells)
{
    this.spells= spells;
}

public int getSpells(){
    return spells;
}

    @Override
public String getDisplayText()
{
    return super.toString() +
        "Spells: " + spells+ "\n";
}
}
```

And finally my Elf sub-class:

```
package project;

public class Elf extends Character{
private int arrows;

public Elf()
{
    super();
    arrows = 0;
    count++;
}

public void setArrows(int arrows)
{
    this.arrows = arrows;
}

public int getArrows(){
    return arrows;
}

    @Override
public String getDisplayText()
{
    return super.toString() +
        "Arrows: " + arrows + "\n";
}
}
```

Comment: In your Project class you can change your `while` loop to a `do...while` to guarantee a minimum of one execution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create one of your `Characters`...

```
Character c = new Elf();
```

You are downcasting the instance to "act" like `Character`, this is very useful feature in Object Oriented Programming, but is causing you issues in this case, as `Character` does not have the methods you are looking for.

Instead, start by assigning the class to a concrete version of the instance...

```
Elf elf = new Elf();
```

Apply the properties you need and then assign it to a `Character` reference...

```
Character c = null;
//...
switch (classChoice) {
    //...
    case "elf":
    {
        Elf elf = new Elf();
        //...
        c = elf;
    }
}
c = elf;
```

for example...

Have a look at the section on [Polymorphism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html) for more details

Comment: That fixed it.  I figured it was something simple I was missing.  Thank you MadProgrammer. =)

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is with these lines

```
Character c = new Wizard();
....
Character c = new Elf();
```

The character class itself doesn't have the setFireballs or SetArrows methods. You need to define the object as a wizard or elf in order to get access to said methods... EG:

```
Elf c = new Elf();
Wizard c = new Wizard();
etc
```

Answer (score 0):

Character c = new Wizard();
Character has neither a setFireBalls method nor a setArrows method.

Answer (score 0):

I have made the some changes to your code..
here is the final code.

> package h;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class he {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Welcome to Lands of the Sun\n");
    Character c = new Wizard();
    Character e = new Elf();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String choice = "y";
    while (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
    {
        System.out.print("Please choose your class (wizard or elf): \n");
        String classChoice = sc.next();
        sc.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Please choose a name for your " + classChoice + ": ");
        String charName = sc.next();
        sc.nextLine();

        int healthVal = (int) (Math.random() * 10) + 1;

        switch (classChoice) {
            case "wizard":
                {

                    c.setName(charName);
                    c.setGold(25);
                    c.setHealth(healthVal);
                    c.setFireballs(10);
                    break;
                }
            case "elf":
                {
                    ;
                    e.setName(charName);
                    e.setGold(25);
                    e.setHealth(healthVal);
                    e.setArrows(10);
                    break;
                }
        }

        System.out.print(c.getName());

        System.out.print("Continue? (y/n): ");
        choice = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println();
    }
}

}
```

Wizard class

> public class Wizard extends Character {
>       private int fireballs;

```
public Wizard()
{
    super();
    fireballs = 0;
    count++;
}

public void setFireballs(int fireballs)
{
    this.fireballs = fireballs;
}

public int getFireballs(){
    return fireballs;
}

    @Override
public String getDisplayText()
{
    return super.toString() +
        "Fireballs: " + fireballs + "\n";
}

    @Override
    public void setArrows(int i) {

    }
```

}

Elf class

> public class Elf extends Character {
>       private int arrows;

```
public Elf()
{
    super();
    arrows = 0;
    count++;
}

public void setArrows(int arrows)
{
    this.arrows = arrows;
}

public int getArrows(){
    return arrows;
}

    @Override
public String getDisplayText()
{
    return super.toString() +
        "Arrows: " + arrows + "\n";
}

    @Override
    public void setFireballs(int i){

    }
```

}

abstract class Character

> public abstract class Character {
>       private String name;
>       private int gold;
>       private int health;
>       public static int count = 0;

```
public Character() {
    name = "";
    gold = 0;
    health = 0;
}

public Character(String name, int gold, int health) {
    this.name = name;
    this.gold = gold;
    this.health = health;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setGold(int gold) {
    this.gold = gold;
}

public void setHealth(int health) {
    this.health = health;
}

public int getHealth() {
    return health;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Name: " + name + "\n" + "Gold: " + gold + "\n" + "Health: "
            + health + "\n";
}

public static int getCount() {
    return count;
}

public abstract String getDisplayText();

public abstract void setFireballs(int i);

public abstract void setArrows(int i);
```

}

hope this helps...